# special pythagorean triplets

Tags: for-loop, pythagorean, triplet

```
def pythagorean(n):
    aAndB = []
    for a in range(150, n-1):
        for b in range(150, n):
            for c in range(150,n+1):
                if (c * c) == a *a + b*b and a + b + c == 1000:
                    aAndB.append(a)
    return aAndB

print(pythagorean(500))
```

So I made this function to find pythagorean triplets that meets criteria a+b+c=1000. When I run this, I get [200,375]. Question is why do I receive two numbers in my list aAndB when I specifically asked to append an item for a?

If I try it with aAndB.append(c), the result shows [425, 425]. How do I fix it only to show exactly one element in the list?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That's because there are 2 values, that satisfy your condition:

```
if (c * c) == a *a + b*b and a + b + c == 1000:
```

You can debug the code or just add more information in array, like that:

```
def pythagorean(n):
    aAndB = []
    for a in range(150, n-1):
        for b in range(150, n):
            for c in range(150,n+1):
                if (c * c) == a * a + b * b and a + b + c == 1000:
                    aAndB.append({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c})
    return aAndB

result = pythagorean(500)
for v in result:
    print(v)
```

So if you want just one element - choose which one from 'result' array.
For example, if you want only first:

```
first_element = None
if len(result) > 0:
    first_element = result[0]
    print('First element:', first_element)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use euclid’s proof of pythagoreas triplets. You can choose any arbitrary numbers greater than zero say `m,n`. According to euclid the triplet will be `a(m∗m−n∗n),b(2∗m∗n),c(m∗m+n∗n)`. Now apply this formula to find out the triplets , say our one value of triplet is 6 then, other two.

```
a(m∗m−n∗n),b(2∗m∗n),c(m∗m+n∗n)
```

It is sure that `b(2∗m∗n)` is obviously even. So now

```
(2∗m∗n)=6 =>(m∗n)=3 =>m∗n=3∗1 =>m=3,n=1
```

You can take any other value rather than 3 and 1 but those two values should hold the product of two numbers is `3 (m∗n=3)`.

Now , when `m` equals 3 and `n` equals 1 then

```
a(m∗m−n∗n)=(3∗3−1∗1)=8 , c(m∗m−n∗n)=(3∗3+1∗1)=10
```

6,8,10 is our triplet for value this our visualization of how generating triplets .

If given number is odd like (9) then slightly modified here, because `b(2∗m∗n)` never be odd. So, here we have to take

```
a(m∗m−n∗n)=7 , (m+n)∗(m−n)=7∗1 , So,(m+n)=7,(m−n)=1
```

Now find `m` and `n` from here then find other two values.

Do code according this , it will generate distinct  triplets and efficiently